# How can I get Geojson data layers to show on a plotly scatter_mapbox plot?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-python

I'm working on a Plotly visualization which overlays data points onto a map. But I'm having a difficulty getting maps in Geojson format to be displayed as layers on the plot. I'm not getting an error, the visualization is rendered, but not the Geojson layers.

[Here's a screenshot of the plot produced.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpYGJ.png) Notice that the data points render properly, but the Geojson data representing an island the points are on does not.

In more detail, I'm working in Jupyter Lab and employing Plotly Express' scatter_mapbox function to generate my visualization. My data is partly contained in CSV files (giving coordinates for the points) and in shape files (one providing a shape representing an island, the other a street map of a city on that island). It was no trouble to get the coordinates in a CSV to display, but I haven't figured out how to get them to display *over the shapefile maps*.

It seemed that the proper way to do it is to put the map data in Geojson format, which Mapbox supports. I used qGIS to do the conversion. I then tried to add a geojson map as a background layer in my plot. Here's my code for the plot (the contents of the sample data files used are at the end of this post):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("exampleDPs.csv")

import geojson
with open('island.geojson') as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="long", hover_name="id", hover_data=["Timestamp"],
                        color_discrete_sequence=["fuchsia"], zoom=15, height=400)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="white-bg")

fig.update_layout(mapbox_layers=[{
            "name": "Island",
            "below": 'traces',
            "sourcetype": "geojson",
            "type": "fill",
            "color": "green",
            "source": [gj]
        }])

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

This generates no error but the island doesn't get rendered (see screenshot). The same is true when I try it with the street map. And the geojson files display properly in other apps, so I don't think they're the problem. I've tried altering any relevant layer settings I could find in the documentation (type as line or fill, colors, display set to true...), and various methods of reading in the Geojson data.

**Additional details:** I'm working with Python 3.8.8 on a Windows 10 machine, Plotly 5.1.0, Pandas 1.5.3, and Geojson 3.0.1.

For reproducing, here is the contents of **exampleDPs.csv**:

```
Timestamp,id,lat,long
01/06/2014 06:28:01,35,36.0762253,24.87468932
01/06/2014 06:28:01,35,36.07622006,24.87459598
01/06/2014 06:28:03,35,36.07621062,24.87444293
01/06/2014 06:28:05,35,36.0762167,24.87425333
01/06/2014 06:28:06,35,36.0762137,24.87416677
01/06/2014 06:28:07,35,36.07619116,24.87405591
01/06/2014 06:28:09,35,36.07619419,24.87390599
01/06/2014 06:28:10,35,36.07618344,24.87381404
01/06/2014 06:28:11,35,36.07616684,24.87373747
```

And here is the content of **island.geojson**:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "island",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "Kronos" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 24.8897, 36.0729 ], [ 24.9519, 36.0538 ], [ 25.0045, 36.0251 ], [ 25.0858, 35.9916 ], [ 25.1431, 35.9629 ], [ 25.2149, 35.9342 ], [ 25.3439, 35.9151 ], [ 25.4252, 35.896 ], [ 25.4922, 35.9103 ], [ 25.5687, 35.9629 ], [ 25.6356, 35.982 ], [ 25.7025, 35.9342 ], [ 25.8412, 35.9247 ], [ 25.9033, 35.9342 ], [ 25.9655, 35.982 ], [ 26.0324, 36.0107 ], [ 26.0324, 35.9725 ], [ 25.9894, 35.9247 ], [ 25.975, 35.8673 ], [ 25.9607, 35.8051 ], [ 25.9177, 35.7717 ], [ 25.8077, 35.7191 ], [ 25.6834, 35.7095 ], [ 25.5591, 35.7287 ], [ 25.4778, 35.7669 ], [ 25.4204, 35.7908 ], [ 25.2722, 35.8004 ], [ 25.1145, 35.7908 ], [ 24.9662, 35.7908 ], [ 24.8993, 35.8195 ], [ 24.8132, 35.8482 ], [ 24.7224, 35.896 ], [ 24.6268, 35.9151 ], [ 24.5168, 35.9486 ], [ 24.4547, 35.9725 ], [ 24.3447, 35.9581 ], [ 24.2826, 35.9581 ], [ 24.1487, 35.9486 ], [ 24.0578, 35.9964 ], [ 24.0483, 36.0442 ], [ 24.0196, 36.0633 ], [ 23.9574, 36.0681 ], [ 23.9383, 36.0681 ], [ 23.8905, 36.0299 ], [ 23.8523, 36.0107 ], [ 23.8331, 36.0251 ], [ 23.8283, 36.092 ], [ 23.8044, 36.1207 ], [ 23.6849, 36.1446 ], [ 23.5845, 36.1542 ], [ 23.5271, 36.1733 ], [ 23.4793, 36.1972 ], [ 23.4315, 36.2402 ], [ 23.465, 36.288 ], [ 23.4746, 36.3263 ], [ 23.575, 36.3358 ], [ 23.661, 36.355 ], [ 23.7805, 36.3837 ], [ 23.8666, 36.3837 ], [ 23.9574, 36.3741 ], [ 24.0292, 36.3598 ], [ 24.1009, 36.3502 ], [ 24.1296, 36.3741 ], [ 24.1774, 36.3932 ], [ 24.2395, 36.355 ], [ 24.3208, 36.3167 ], [ 24.4355, 36.288 ], [ 24.5025, 36.2593 ], [ 24.5694, 36.2546 ], [ 24.6172, 36.2259 ], [ 24.7224, 36.1733 ], [ 24.7846, 36.1398 ], [ 24.7989, 36.1398 ], [ 24.8515, 36.0968 ], [ 24.8897, 36.0729 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

My data is sampled from the VAST Challenge 2021 Mini Challenge 2. That Geojson file represents a fictional Greek island.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: the source parameter for layers should not have brackets around it. That was all that was needed to fix the problem.